# Get tcp/udp protocol name(string) based on port number?

Tags: javascript, php, python, algorithm, protocols

The question could apply to any *web oriented* language.

As the title says, I would like string based on the port number:

For example:

```
protocol = get_protocol_name(22)
print protocol
```

This should print out "ssh". A more verbosed version would make sense:

```
protocol = get_protocol_name(21, true)
print protocol
```

Could return print out "File Transfer Protocol".

The function has no complexity, the purpose of the question **is not** how the code would be, but if there is any implementation already embedded in the languages.

Comment: this has nothing to do with javascript and php, I removed the tags and my edit got accepted, so that seems to be the "right" way. why did you re-add them?

Comment: Read the first sentence of the question, I just put the examples in python but the question applies to any language.

Comment: by that logic, you'd have to add every language tag there is (you didn't)

Comment: Feel free to add them, I am interested if there is a solution in those languages as well. Other option is to spam stackoverflow with the same question for each language...

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at python's [socket module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.getservbyport)

```
>>> import socket
>>> socket.getservbyport(23)
'telnet'
```